# How to set after onclick it include image and div span contents in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a code using CSS sprite , as the code is working although i clicking on the image and the whole div contents change color include the contents word . But when i clicking on the contents word which stacked with images indeed the contents word does the changes of the color but the images still remain as the same without changing to blue.

Can we do it in Jquery method to make this function work ?

```css
/*Hide the Radio Button*/

.games-sub-menu input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
/*Set a box for the label, this is what is clicked on*/

.games-sub-menu label {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
/*Set Images...this would work better with sprites*/

.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image1");
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image1");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG2 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Image2");
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG2 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image2");
}
```

```html
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
  <ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix">
    <li class="tab1 current">
      <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg1">
      <label class="topimgG1" for="rdoImg1"></label>
      <span>编辑精选</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2 current">
      <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg2">
      <label class="topimgG2" for="rdoImg2"></label>
      <span>编辑精选</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Image of the div  :

[image]

Comment: Can you post your JS also? And perhaps create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @IvanModric Hi , im new on development as im student , thus i have no clue on js method

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to achieve? When a button is clicked it should change color?

Comment: @IvanModric what i trying to archieve is when button clicked , the image should change to other image

Comment: It looks like it does that already, or should the change be permanent? If so: what should happen when the same image is clicked again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html code that way, that the `span` which holds the text will be the child element of the label, that way, clik on the text will also be click on the label which will change the check state of the input, and your css will change too:

```
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
  <ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix">
    <li class="tab2 current">
      <label class="topimgG2" for="rdoImg2">
         <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg2">
         <span>编辑精选</span>      
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an example, I changed also your css a little bit:

```css
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}

.games-sub-menu label {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1 span::before {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  content: "\00a0";
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image1");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG2 span::before {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  content: "\00a0";
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Image2");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1 input[type=radio]:checked + span::before {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image1");
}

.games-sub-menu label.topimgG2 input[type=radio]:checked +  span::before {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image2");
}
```

```html
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
  <ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix">
    <li class="tab1 current">
      <label class="topimgG1" for="rdoImg1">
        <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg1">
        <span>编辑精选</span>        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2 current">
      <label class="topimgG2" for="rdoImg2">
        <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg2">
        <span>编辑精选</span>        
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi your code not the correct way , due the word was moved inside the image

Comment: "Moving words" outside the image is just about the css.

Answer (score 0):

On `click` event just change the background image of that particular div whereever you are clicking.

By jQuery you can remove previous `class` and add another `class` which has different background property.

Example -

```
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1Clicked {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=ImageChangedImage");
}
```

In javascript `click` event:

```
$(this).closest('label').removeClass('topimgG1');
$(this).closest('label').removeClass('topimgG1Clicked');
```